# MySQL query to get only hour rounded data to the nearest 30 minutes

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have data stored in UTC timezone in the database, I need to query the database such that I get 24 rows per day of data and it should be based as 00:00, 01:00, 23:00 in that timezone. So CET would between 01:00 to 01:00 (GMT+1) and so on.

```
timestampData               value
2021-02-13 10:00:00           23
2021-02-13 10:30:00           25
2021-02-13 11:00:00           22
2021-02-13 11:30:00           20
```

so if I were to query CET timezone, I would get data from 2021-02-13 10:00:00 , 2021-02-13 11:00:00  , etc

but if I query IST timezone: I would need data for 2021-02-13 10:30:00 , 2021-02-13 11:30:00, etc

Comment: There is not enough info in the question to fully understand what you are trying to do but check out the CONVERT_TZ() in MySQL it may help you.

Comment: so essentially, I have data that is stored every 30 mins, so that it covers all timezones. 
Now, if I am in CET timezone. It's UTC+1 so, I would be taking values of 
01:00, 02:00, 03:00...etc

But if I am in IST
I need to take values as: 
05:30, 06:30, 07:30, and so on.

Comment: So can you use CONVERT_TZ to convert from CET to IST?

Comment: Sure, but it will also include the data for minute 30, essentially, the database has 48 rows per day, but I need to query only 24; those of hours.

Comment: I cannot picture what you are asking for so please add some things to your question, a sample of your data (as CREATE and INSERT statements), the SQL script you currently have, the output you are getting and the output you want.